# How to install Gnome-Commander 1.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, filemanager

Decided to try out Ubuntu and see if I can move from windows to it permanently, or at least have alternate OS for development purposes. The first part of it is having similar programs (like total commander). I have absolutely no experience with Linux (Unix?) based OS.

Since `apt-get` for `gnome-commander` gets me an older version without tabs I wanted to get the last version, from here [gcmd.github.io](http://gcmd.github.io/download.html)

When running `./configure` I was able to install most of the necessary stuff but I don't know what to do with this one:

```
if gtk+ >= 2.8.0 exists... configure: error: no
```

I installed the gtk+3.1.2 from [www.gtk.org](http://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php) following the Ubuntu `CompilingEasyHowTo` Guide, but when I run the `./configure` for the `gnome-commander` it still stops there.

Any suggestions for the next step?

Solution EDIT:

Thanks to Alexander Martin for the answer. Additionally (and for the future reference) I had to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgnomeui-dev 
sudo apt-get install libunique-dev
sudo apt-get install scrollkeeper
```

For most of those I had to search the askubuntu and other sites for answers. Is there a way to find which package to install for `libgnomeui` etc rather than relying on other sources? Like a application (or terminal) where I can just type in `libgnomeui` and get which package should I `sudo apt-get install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with installing GTK+ 3 over 2 is that the software you are compiling probably requires GTK+ 2 over 3.  According to the [GTK+ 3 reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html)  software needs to be adjusted by the developers to build against GTK+ 3.  You'll want to install the most up-to-date version of GTK+ 2.

You can install it easily via (it's at version 2.24.23):

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

e: I can't comment yet on posts - but the Synaptic Package Manager is a program you can install that makes it easy to find package names and install them.  Sorry I should have originally mentioned this. You can get in the Ubuntu Software Centre or by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Or you can use [apt-cache](http://www.ccl.net/cca/software/UNIX/updating-redhat/apt-howto/how-to-use-apt-cache.html) but Synaptic is much easier.

Comment: I edited my original answer is response to the question's edits.